# not able to find wijmo drop down arrow css

Tags: css, wijmo

i am designing some forms in wijmo and html mix. the dropdown size is different and drop down arrow is taking too much space, where can i find the css to reduce the arrow width of wj-input-date or advice if bootstrap can handle it

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12   " style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;margin-top:5px;">
            <wj-input-date style="width: 100%"
                    [(value)]="application.dealData.settlementDate"
                    [format]="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
                    [mask]="'99/99/9999'"
                    [isRequired]="false"
                    [isDisabled]="financeDisabled">
            </wj-input-date>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wj-input-group-btn {
    position: relative;
    width: 26px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

overwrite this according to you.
this css exist in wijmo.css

Comment: Can you maybe give an example, or screenshot that this is working / where it can be found.